# como preencher e manter preenchida a altura da tela com uma div usando css puro?

Tags: html, css, div

sou novo aqui no stackoverflow e estou procurando uma ajuda muito comum (de acordo com o que eu pesquisei aqui)...

eu quero preencher a altura da tela usando uma DIV com uma cor qualquer, mas de acordo com o que eu já tentei, a DIV só preenche o conteúdo da primeira tela...

se o texto for maior que a primeira tela e eu tiver que rolar a tela usando o mouse, a DIV acaba e volta para a cor do fundo do texto...

eu quero fazer isso usando somente HTML, DIVs e CSS Puro...

obrigado, até a próxima e Feliz Páscoa para todos ;-D